# HTML countdown timer with sequenced events

Tags: html

In HTML, i have a countdown timer, courtesy of w3, but I can’t seem to figure out how, once the time has expired, to reload the timer with the next date. For example I want to countdown between holidays. I assume I need to compare to today’s date, but not sure what that module looks like either. Any help would be appreciated. Thx

var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 1, 2021 01:37:25").getTime();

var countDownDate = new Date("Feb 14, 2021 01:37:25").getTime();

var countDownDate = new Date("Mar 17, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

```
<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

 // Get today's date and time
 var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 *     60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
   clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, but I think you want to add a new interval when you clear the previous one. So after `clearInterval(x)` in your code, you need to `setInterval` again with that function and the new expiry date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```js
const dates = [
  new Date("Jan 1, 2021 01:37:25").getTime(),
  new Date("Feb 14, 2021 01:37:25").getTime(),
  new Date("Mar 17, 2021 15:37:25").getTime(),
];

const interval = setInterval(tick, 1000);

function nextDate() {
  const now = Date.now();
  return dates.find(date => date > now);
}

function tick() {
  const date = nextDate();
  if (!date) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
  let distance = date - Date.now();
  
  const days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  distance -= days * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  
  const hours = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  distance -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
  
  const minutes = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60));
  distance -= minutes * 1000 * 60;
  
  const seconds = Math.floor(distance / 1000);
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `Time until ${new Date(date).toLocaleDateString()}: ${days} days, ${hours} hours, ${minutes} minutes, ${seconds} seconds`;
}
```

It only clears the interval when there are no more dates in future left. You can change the dates by changing the array in the `dates` variable. But be aware, that you must keep the ascending sort of the dates.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for, thanks for working the boards!